# Use MaxBackupIndex in DailyRollingFileAppender -log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Can someone please tell me how to use MaxBackupIndex in DailyRollingFileAppender.I know that the RollingFileAppender supports a maxBackupIndex property, but is there any workarounds for using MaxBackupIndex in DailyRollingFileAppender?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This feature is not available in current stable version (1.2) of Log4j.

Anyway you can explore the following:
http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender

Comment: Thank you very much, worked for me!

Just unpackaged the .jar to a folder, created a .java file containing the code, compiled it into a class, dropped it in the [ log4j-1.2.16\org\apache\log4j ] folder, zipped up the entire contents of the log4j-1.2.16 folder and renamed as a jar, included in build path, and referenced new class in my log4j.xml configuration :)

Comment: log4j recommends the contributed RollingFileAppender instead of its own, and it does support rollover with MaxBackupIndex and a TimeBasedRollingPolicy.

See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html

Comment: @jp093121 May I ask how do you compile the .java file into .class file? I tried copied the content to a .java file then compile it, but many error came up, how do you solve it?

Comment: @jp093121 Never mind, I've already solve it, but it seems this method not work perfectly, I mean sometimes it won't work, is that bugs or I did anything wrong?