# How to configure log4j to only keep log files for the last seven days?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following logging problem with several Java applications using `log4j` for logging:

I want log files to be rotated daily, like

```
log.2010-09-10
log.2010-09-09
log.2010-09-08
log.2010-09-07
log.2010-09-06
log.2010-09-05
log.2010-09-04
```

But for data security reasons we are not allowed to keep log files for longer than seven days at my company. So the generation of the next next log file `log.2010-09-11` should trigger the deletion of `log.2010-09-04`. Is it possible to configure such a behaviour with `log4j`? If not, do you know another elegant solution for this kind of logging problem?

Comment: This is not duplicate, RollingFileAppender is not what OP wants, because only DailyRollingFileAppender rotates files daily!

Comment: There is solution for your answer using log4j and java - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58729657/7179509

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can perform your housekeeping in a separate script which can be cronned to run daily. Something like this:

```
find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Just for reference: An anonymous user suggested an edit appending the following: "To expand upon that, if you have large logs/want to save disk space, you can compress the rotated logs and then remove compressed logs X days old. I do something like:

 find /path/to/logs -type f -name "*.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" -exec bzip2 '{}' \; && find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime +7 -name "*.bz2" -exec rm -f '{}' \;"

Answer (score 60):

I assume you're using RollingFileAppender? In which case, it has a property called `MaxBackupIndex` which you can set to limit the number of files. For example:

```
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=7
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Comment: But that would keep the last 700kB of logging data, wouldn't it? I want to keep logging data for the last 7 days, independent of the log file size.

Comment: You actually get a warning that `MaxBackupIndex` is not a valid member of `DailyRollingFileAppender`.  To my knowledge, there is no way to do this with log4j.  You have to remove the days yourself.

Comment: i dont think log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1 will only keep 1 log file on server. I had this setting, but do see the old file is still there.

Comment: log4j recommends the contributed RollingFileAppender instead of its own, and it does support rollover with MaxBackupIndex and a TimeBasedRollingPolicy.

See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html

Comment: After configuring MaxBackupIndex, and seeing it not work with org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender, I had a look at the source.  I only saw MaxBackupIndex in the comments.  I am inclined to think the comment was copy/pasted and MaxBackupIndex is not implemented.

Comment: `maxBackupIndex` is a field on org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender, it just doesn't exist on org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender (which is a different class, extra ".rolling." in the package name). I'm on log4j 1.2.17

Answer (score 15):

According to the following post, you can't do this with log4j: [Use MaxBackupIndex in DailyRollingFileAppender -log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896530/use-maxbackupindex-in-dailyrollingfileappender-log4j)

As far as I know, this functionality was supposed to make it into log4j 2.0 but that effort got sidetracked. According to the logback website, logback is the intended successor to log4j so you might consider using that.

There's an API called SLF4J which provides a common API to logging. It will load up the actual logging implementation at runtime so depending on the configuration that you have provided, it might use java.util.log or log4j or logback or any other library capable of providing logging facilities. There'll be a bit of up-front work to go from using log4j directly to using SLF4J but they provide some tools to automate this process. Once you've converted your code to use SLF4J, switching logging backends should simply be a case of changing the config file.

Answer (score 10):

log4j2 now has support to delete old logs.

Take a look at [DefaultRolloverStrategy tag](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy) and at the snippets below.

It

- creates up to 10 archives on the same day,
- will parse the ${baseDir} directory that you define under the Properties tag at max depth of 2 with log filename matching "app-*.log.gz"
- delete logs older than 7 days but keep the most recent 5 logs if your most recent 5 logs are older than 7 days.

  ```
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10">
    <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
      <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz">
        <IfLastModified age="7d">
          <IfAny>
            <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="5" />
          </IfAny>
        </IfLastModified>
      </IfFileName>
    </Delete>
  </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
  ```

A good debug option is if you set:

```
<Configuration status="trace">
```

and use testMode Option like this:

```
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
          <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" testMode="true">
            <IfFileName glob="*.log" />
            <IfLastModified age="7d" />
          </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```

You can see in console log what files would get deleted without deleting the files right away.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a [DailyRollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)

Edit: after reading this worrying statement:

> DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization
> issues and data loss. The log4j extras companion includes alternatives
> which should be considered for new deployments and which are discussed
> in the documentation for org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.

from the above URL (which I never realized before), then the [log4j-extras](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/index.html) looks to be a better option.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this appender [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/02/grails-goodness-use-timeandsizerollinga.html) that does what you want, it can be configured to keep a specific number of files that have been rolled over by date.

Download: http://www.simonsite.org.uk/download.htm

Example (groovy):

```
new TimeAndSizeRollingAppender(name: 'timeAndSizeRollingAppender',
   file: 'logs/app.log', datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd',
   maxRollFileCount: 7, compressionAlgorithm: 'GZ',
   compressionMinQueueSize: 2,
   layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n"))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another option **DailyRollingFileAppender**. but it lacks the auto delete (keep 7 days log) feature you looking for

sample

```
log4j.appender.DRF=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRF.File=example.log
log4j.appender.DRF.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

I do come across something call **org.apache.log4j.CompositeRollingAppender**, which is combine both the features of the **RollingFileAppender** (maxSizeRollBackups, no. of backup file) and **DailyRollingFileAppender** (roll by day).

But have not tried that out, seems is not the standard 1.2 branch log4j feature.

Comment: `CompositeRollingAppender` sounded promising, but I took a look at its code, and it (still!) implements deleting old files only when rolling over files based on size, not when rolling over based on date. A shame, as that shouldn't be hard to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Use the setting `log4j.appender.FILE.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern`, e.g. `log4j.appender.FILE.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=F:/logs/filename.log.%d{dd}.gz` for keeping logs one month before rolling over.

I didn't wait for one month to check but I tried with mm (i.e. minutes) and confirmed it overwrites, so I am assuming it will work for all patterns.

Comment: Creative solution but for this OP it would only work if they included the name of the day of the week (Mon, Tues, Wed, etc...) since he only wants to keep 7 days.  Plus, do you know if this overwrites the original or just appends to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can configure a cron job using tmpwatch.

Most Linux systems have a tmpwatch cron job that cleans up the /tmp directory.  You can add another that monitors your logging directory and deletes files over 7 days old.

If you are using a different system, there are probably equivalent utilities.

Comment: redhat family only

Answer (score 0):

Inspite of starting a chrone job, for the task, we can use log4j2.properties file in config folder of logstash. Have a look at the link below, this will be helpful.

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/7482

Answer (score 0):

My script based on @dogbane's answer

/etc/cron.daily/hbase

```
#!/bin/sh
find /var/log/hbase -type f -name "phoenix-hbase-server.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" -exec bzip2 {} ";"
find /var/log/hbase -type f -regex ".*.out.[0-9][0-9]?" -exec bzip2 {} ";"
find /var/log/hbase -type f -mtime +7 -name "*.bz2" -exec rm -f {} ";"
```

/etc/cron.daily/tomcat

```
#!/bin/sh
find /opt/tomcat/log/ -type f -mtime +1 -name "*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].*log" -exec bzip2 {} ";"
find /opt/tomcat/log/ -type f -mtime +1 -name "*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].txt" -exec bzip2 {} ";"
find /opt/tomcat/log/ -type f -mtime +7 -name "*.bz2" -exec rm -f {} ";"
```

because Tomcat rotate needs one day delay.

Answer (score -1):

The class `DailyRollingFileAppender` uses the **DatePattern** option to specify the rolling schedule. This pattern should follow the `SimpleDateFormat` conventions from **Std. Ed. v1.4.2**. So, we have to use `E` option (Day in week). For example:

```
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'EEE"/>
```

See more about `DailyRollingFileAppender` class from `log4j` **javadoc** [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html). Unfortunately the Java 1.4.2 documentation is no longer online, but you can download a copy [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/).

Comment: it would be helpful to explain in a little more detail and link to the documentation

Answer (score -1):

I had set:

> ```
> log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
> log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
> # Archive log files (Keep one year of daily files)
> log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=367
> ```

Like others before me, the DEBUG option showed me the error:

> log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in
>   org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.

Here is an idea I have not tried yet, suppose I set the DatePattern such that the files overwrite each other after the required time period. To retain a year's worth I could try setting:

> ```
> log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'MM-dd
> ```

Would it work or would it cause an error ?
Like that it will take a year to find out, I could try:

> ```
> log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'dd
> ```

but it will still take a month to find out.

Comment: What was the result of this?  Do the files overwrite?

Answer (score -2):

I create this Methode and call it by closing the application:

```
  public void deleteFiles(){

    File f = new File("log");
    File[] fileArray = f.listFiles();
    double timenow = System.currentTimeMillis();

    double olderTenDays = timenow - 864000000;// MS for ten days

    for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {

        if(fileArray[i].lastModified()< olderTenDays )
           fileArray[i].delete();
    }
 }
```