# How to configure log4j to only keep log files for the last n days?

Tags: java, date, logging, cron

My name is Luis Ribeiro and I am trying to set log4j, so that it will delete the older rotate logs.

The solution that we have for now is to use cron with a script.
For example like this: [How to configure log4j to only keep log files for the last seven days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683364/how-to-configure-log4j-to-only-keep-log-files-for-the-last-seven-days)

But here are some major problems:

1. Work with hundred of machines(n)
2. Work with many crons in many machines(n * m)
3. Work with different structures and OS(n * m * z)
4. Cron will delete even when the application stop and there is a lost of information

The ideal is that when application runs, log4j will take care complete of the log rotation.

- It will rotate once a day: RollingFile: Daily and filePattern="logs/${filename}.[ %d{yyyy-MM-dd} | -%i | any type of counter ].log.gz" with TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
- actual log and n rotation files are kept. Older are deleted: app.log, app.{-1 day}.log.gz,..., app.{-n days}.log.gz
- The pattern name isn't important it can be a number in the file name
- We cannot use size as trigger. We don't know how much the program will do during the day. Log size varies very, very much
- It should be structure and os independent. We prefer to enhance the log4j Properties or XMl file, than adding scripts and cron triggers.

I try to use the DefaultRolloverStrategy with TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy. But the are problems:

1. filePattern=${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz will result in: app.log, app.{-1 day}-1.log.gz, app.{-2 day}-1.log.gz,..., app.{-(n + 1) days}-1.log.gz,... => It will never be deleted
2. filePattern=${filename}-%i.log.gz result in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pattern does not contain a date

Is there any away to enhance the log4j so it will take care of all these tasks?

With best regards,
Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because DailyRollingFileAppender does not have attribute MaxBackupIndex, so you have to remove log by yourself.

Or you can perform crontab for housecleaning like:

```
find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime +dayToKeep -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will keep searching