# Log4j - how to roll over log files after 14 days

Tags: java, log4j

I am creating a logger by using log4j's `RollingFileAppender`. Currently the roll back is happening based on `MaxFileSize` and `MaxBackupIndex`.
 I need to keep the generated log files for 14 days.

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender    
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=/path/mylog.log 
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=50MB 
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxBackUpIndex=30
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683364/how-to-configure-log4j-to-only-keep-log-files-for-the-last-seven-days) help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DailyRollingFileAppender` to rollover based on time. But, it can only,

> Is is possible to specify monthly, weekly, half-daily, daily, hourly,
>   or minutely rollover schedules.

and doesn't seem to have a an option to specify the number of backups. Also,

> DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization
>   issues and data loss. The log4j extras companion includes alternatives
>   which should be considered for new deployments and which are discussed
>   in the documentation for org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.

**Ex:**

```
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=app.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

You can then clear out old files, through a cron job, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683364/how-to-configure-log4j-to-only-keep-log-files-for-the-last-seven-days).Check out the log4j [Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) once.

Comment: Thanks .    Can we use same RollingFileAppender and add rolling policy (TimeBasedRollingPolicy) in that case how to set filenamepattern??

Comment: Sure, but that's not a default part of `log4j` 1 its a part of `log4j extras`.

Comment: Just add `log4j.appender.LOGFILE.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy log4j.appender.LOGFILE.FileNamePattern=/path/mylog-.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log` remeber to add the extras jar.Also If you're open to changing loggin frameowrks i'd recomend log4j2/logback, log4j1 ended a long time back.