# Log4J Log Rotation

Tags: log4j

We have a business requirement to keep last 7 days log
Can we use log4j to delete old 7 days log.

We are using

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enhanced version of the DailyRollingFileAppender [Use MaxBackupIndex in DailyRollingFileAppender -log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/896530/449161)

Otherwise you could create a cron job that just deletes the logs over a certain age:

```
find /your/log/dir -name "*.log" -ctime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```